# How to decode and get values from API response that is stored in a dictionary in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an API response that is stored in a dictionary, I have created structs in a different folders but when I try to decode them using decode method it throws an error, the error mentions that "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." , here is the code and structs I have built:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var cityButtons: [UIButton]!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func handleSelection(_ sender: UIButton) {
        cityButtons.forEach{ (button) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                button.isHidden = !button.isHidden
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
            
        }
    }
    enum Cities:String {
        case amman = "Amman"
        case azzerqa = "Az zerqa"
        case irbid = "Irbid"
        case aqaba = "Aqaba"
    }
    @IBAction func cityTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let title = sender.currentTitle, let City = Cities(rawValue: title)
            
            else {
            return
        }
        var city:String
        switch City {
        case .amman:
            city = "Amman"
        case .azzerqa:
                  city = "zerqa"
        case .irbid:
            city = "Irbid"
        case .aqaba:
            city = "Aqaba"
        }
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key={ket}&q=\(city)")
        guard url != nil else {
            print("error creating URL Object")
            return
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy , timeoutInterval: 10)
        let headers = ["Content-Type" : "application/json"]
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in
            if error == nil && data != nil {
                do {
                    let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any]
                 let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    print(dictionary)
                    do {
                        let weatherdatadecoded = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: data!)
                        print(weatherdatadecoded)
                    }
                    catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

and here are the structs (each one is in a separate file):

```
import Foundation

struct WeatherData : Codable {
    var location: Location?
    var current: Current?
}

import Foundation

struct Location : Codable {
    var name: String = ""
    var region: String = ""
    var localtime: String = ""
    var country: String = ""
}

import Foundation

struct Current : Codable {
    var temp_c = 0.0
    var is_day = false
    var condition: Condition?
}

import Foundation

struct Condition : Codable {
    var text: String = ""
    var icon: String = ""
    var code: Int = 0
}
```

Comment: You will get a much more meaningful error message if you change `print(error.localizedDescription)` to `print(error)`. Also, you should remove the api key before posting your code on-line

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have removed the key and tried the error print, I got this error:
typeMismatch(Swift.Bool, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "current", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "is_day", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Bool but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Did you analyse the error, does it tell you anything?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have figured it out, the is_day in struct was declared as a bool while its value is int, I changed it and it worked, thank you

Comment: Great, those error messages can be a bit intimidating at first but once you learn how to read them they are both clear and useful.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson indeed, I thank you